# How to drag a UIView onto the Canvas in Xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, uiview

I am following a tutorial for iphone app development. I am still new to this, so this may be a stupid question. The tutorial asks specifically for me to "Open the utilities area and drag a UIView onto the canvas."

Only problem is, when I search in my utilities, I don't have a UIview object. The only hits I get are View Controller and View. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIView` == `View` in your Xcode-InterfaceBuilder's object library.

Description:
*Represents a rectangular region in which it draws and receives events.*

Answer (score 1):

Click on the View object - a little window will pop open describing a "View". You will see that a "View" object is actually a UIView object.

Note that you can gain more information about the various objects (in addition to their "real" name) by doing this.